# How to disable the dropdown menu of select when the select only has one item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I'm using 'select' widget from angularstrap.

I'm wondering how to prevent the dropdown menu for the select only having one item. The only one item has been selected by default, how to prevent the click event on select to show the dropdown menu?

Is it a missing feature of angularstrap?

Check the `Single select` in [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/NLYDffPWfg43w4YtYzix?p=preview)

Comment: how do you mean the dropdown menu for the select only having one item? It has as many items you add to it.

Comment: The number of options of 'select' widget depends on the model. It might have several items or only one for some cases. I would like to the dropdown menu won't pop up when clicking 'select' widget if there is only one option of 'select'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not angularstrap feature, but you can use attributes like `ng-hide`, `ng-show` or `ng-if` to hide specific `<div>` element when your select has only one item.

**UPDATE:**
According to your example, change your `Single select` section:

```
<label>Single select:&nbsp;</label>
<button ng-if="icons.length > 1" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectedIcon" data-html="1" bs-options="icon.value as icon.label for icon in icons" bs-select>
  Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<button ng-if="icons.length === 1" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectedIcon" data-html="1">
  {{icons[0].value}}
</button>
```

I can't add gear icon, but I hope it's easy fix ;)

Comment: Pls check the example in updated question. The dropdown `<div>` is created by angularstrap, not by app itself.

Comment: Your solution works in select only having one item. However the model **selectedIcon** won't be updated when changing the option if there are more than one option. See the symptom in updated example.

Comment: @Kane It works when you use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`. I **guess** it may be problem with `$scope`.

Comment: Sorry for accepting it late. The demo code works fine now. Something strange still is happening in my project. The model object still can NOT be updated after the option is changed. Obviously the controller of my project is more complicated than the demo. Anyway you deserved it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the same as @Egan Wolf mentioned, but the problem with that is the UX. It's not so nice to show the user something different just because the data has changed or not enough for a select box. I'd make it disabled, so that the user will get a clear visual feedback that he/she can't select more.